# Motivation behind Binet form and its generalization to arbitrary coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Binet form (http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binet_Form) gives a closed-form solution to $n^{th}$ term in a series with recurrence relation as below

$U_{n}=m\cdot U_{m-1}+U_{m-2}$

I have two questions -

1. What was the motivation for finding closed form solution for this particular recurrence relation, rather than a generalized $U_{n}=m_1\cdot U_{m-1}+m_2\cdot U_{m-2}$? Was Binet trying to solve some practical problem in which that relation was seen?
2. *Can* the generalized form proof be arrived at using the matrix eigenvalue-eigenvector trick as used in the Binet form proof? (I'm not asking for actual proof).

Comment: 2. Yes. Any linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients (of which the ones you mention are examples) can be solved using tools from linear algebra.

Comment: Indeed, I'd encourage you to try it, it's a good exercise.

Comment: Finding a closed form is crucial. Suppose you don't have any and you want the value for $n=10^6$. Would you compute (and store) all the previous results ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici By motivation I mean some practical motivation, whether that relation was observed in nature of elsewhere. It seems interesting that he chose the coefficients `m` and `1`. @others thanks for encouragement, I'm trying to solve generalized form.